# Multiple twitter login at same time IOS app

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, social-framework

I have an application that i need to integrate with twitter login, for logging in via their twitter account. In the application we also have Twitter sharing option. Here i want to implement functionality to choose their account in which account they want to share the tweet. If user is logged in for only one account, then there should be provision to login to another account without logging out of existing logged-in account.

Comment: Have a look at the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) library. You can instantiate several instances of STTwitterAPI, each one managing a separate Twitter account. You can use the account(s) defined in iOS settings as well as other Twitter accounts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

====>Download Third Party Class FSHTwitterEngine.

{

[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"6XITOIDiXNajx7TQMKOh8qDxj" andSecret:@"w4F44ATueFsarNjGQ9WDdEudJCBJ8P0o5zeNON5bP9hIKhGls6"];

```
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];

    UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {


        NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");

        [self performSelector:@selector(TwitterPostMessage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];



    }];
    [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

-(void)TwitterPostMessage
{

```
UIImage *aimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mark"];

// [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:@"Hepp adsfihdf sdfhihdsfh" withImageData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(aimg)];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
        //NSString *tweet = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        // id returned = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:@"Post of image"];

        id returned = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:@"Hi Successfully Post Twitter..." withImageData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(aimg)];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        NSString *title = nil;
        NSString *message = nil;

        if ([returned isKindOfClass:[NSError class]])
        {
            NSError *error = (NSError *)returned;
            title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %d",error.code];

            message = error.localizedDescription;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@",returned);
            title = @"Tweet Posted";
            message = @"Post of image";
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            @autoreleasepool {
                UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [av show];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Well, this really compounds about 5 different topics in to one, and we can't write your entire app for you, but here are some helpful pointers.

When it comes to twitter, I use the STTwitter API (https://github.com/nst/STTwitter). What this does is takes all the twitter code, and dumbs it down for us less objective-c inclined programmers. The "README" file contains more information about what you'd be needing. You can find the developer tutorial at http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2014/6/17/xcode-5-tutorial-ios-7-app-only-authentication-twitter-api-version-11. This also allows you to download the project to test, and copy and paste code from.

Youtube and Google are also great sources to find information. Right now your request is quite broad and encompases quite a few different aspects of twitter integration, work on them one at a time from the ground up.